# ListView shows wrong (double) data

Tags: android, listview

Log shows as a response from API:

```
{"result":{"list":[
    {"id":"8","name":"Girl","last_name":"","username":"girl1_firstname girl1_lastname","photo":"http:\/\/new.mmm.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/dsp_media\/user_photos\/user_8\/thumbs\/thumb_8_girl3.jpg"},
    {"id":"9","name":"","last_name":"","username":"girl2_firstname girl2_lastname","photo":"http:\/\/new.mmm.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/dsp_media\/user_photos\/user_9\/thumbs\/thumb_9_girl2.jpg"},
    {"id":"92","name":"Artem","last_name":"Bogomaz","username":"artem_bogomaz","photo":"http:\/\/new.mmm.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/dsp_media\/user_photos\/user_92\/thumbs\/thumb_92_IMG_7350.jpg"},
    {"id":"215","name":"Rafal","last_name":"Sob","username":"rafal","photo":"http:\/\/new.mmm.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/dsp_dating\/images\/female-generic.jpg"},
    {"id":"218","name":"rafal","last_name":"Sokk","username":"rafalek2","photo":"http:\/\/new.mmm.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/dsp_dating\/images\/female-generic.jpg"},
    {"id":"220","name":"Rafal","last_name":"Sokk","username":"rafalek3","photo":"http:\/\/new.mmm.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/dsp_dating\/images\/male-generic.jpg"},
    {"id":"221","name":"Rafal","last_name":"Sokk","username":"rafalek4","photo":"http:\/\/new.mmm.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/dsp_dating\/images\/female-generic.jpg"},
    {"id":"281","name":"Bdbdhd","last_name":"Sjhsjdjd","username":"Andrzej12","photo":"http:\/\/new.mmm.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/dsp_dating\/images\/male-generic.jpg"}    
]}}
```

But in my ListView I see double `girl1_firstname girl1_lastname` instead of `Andrzej12`, why?

When I reload data from API I get on last position correct `Andrzej12` and a next couple times I saw `Andrzej12` in `ListView`, but sometimes it still shows `girl1_firstname girl1_lastname`... Data response from API always show the same data with `Andrzej12`, why instead of this I got other record?!

My code in adapter is like:

```
if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.connections_list_view_single, parent, false);

//rest of the code
}
```

but `rest of the code` should be below the brackets.

Comment: Show your adapter code.

Comment: How can anybody answer your questions without actually seeing what your code looks like?

Comment: I do a stupid mistake... All my code in `getView` was in `if(convertView == null)` brackets. I left only `LayoutInflater inflater` and `convertView`...